# WL.Client.login() then nsurlerrordomain error 1012

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, nsurlerrordomain

Worklight 6.2 building a hybrid application targeting iPad - we get the symptoms described below in the xCode Simulator irrespective of exactly which target device we select.

The application currently attempts a call to

```
WL.Client.login()
```

from within `wlCommoninit()`

Our target server is a full WL Server running on a Liberty instance on a remote machine, we use HTTPS and a specified IP Address

```
https://w.x.y.z:443/worklight
```

We have adjusted the Deploy Target and rebuilt the app before running XCode.

The `WL.Client.login()` error callback fires and we see log messages indicating that we are attempting to hit the correct URL. We also see this error message

```
NSURLErrorDomain error -1012
```

We do have a complex network setup, with a firewall between the iOS simulator and the server and yet if we run up Safari on the simulated device we can correctly access the URL.

Questions:

1. Does that NSURLErrorDomain reflect the cause of the failure? Or is it just part of the error processing?
2. Any suggestions for further diagnosis?

Comment: You'll probably want to expend on your complex setup...?

Comment: @IdanAdar I know something about this scenario. I think the point is that as far as djna knows right now, it's a black box. But the URL can be accessed from Safari, which points towards a client (app) issue in my mind?

Comment: I just edited the Q to add a missing `:` after https. Was that missing from your original URL? Could potentially explain the problem...

Comment: Doubtful, as he says it works in Preview (although I am assuming here the test in preview is done on the remote server and not the development server).

Comment: Actually he might not be referring to Preview. I don't know what does "safari on the simulated device" mean. Safari Mobile in iOS Simulator?

Comment: @IdanAdar, not sure what you mean by "Preview" here. It does load as a "Mobile Web App" in the Safari browser on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Can we check whether it fails in HTTP as well? If it does, perhaps wireshark logs will then help.

Comment: Otherwise, there is IMO just not enough information here to understand what's going on.

Comment: What certificate are you using for SSL? Is it a self signed one, or one from a commonly trusted source, such as Verisign? I am not too familiar with Objective C, but that error is NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication, which might have to do with the certificate not being trusted by the device. If it is from your own custom CA, you can import the certificate into your device and have it trusted there. A sample way of how to do this is explained here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_installing_root_CA_iOS.html?lang=en

Comment: For reference, here are what the NSURLErrorDomain errors are: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Comment: And you might also want to try these things: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29125650/2245921

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation indicated that we did have the wrong URL configured. It seems that

```
NSURLErrorDomain error -1012
```

is not in itself an indicator of the problem. Rather, the error follows from the failure to reach the specified host. Conclusion: study the logs prior top that NSURLErrorDomain message.